# Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'INVALID'

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm going through a book (Zend Framework, A Beginners Guide) and there's quite a few errors in this book, but luckily I've figured all of them out thus far, besides this one.

I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant
>   'INVALID' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\zend\square\library\Square\Form\ItemCreate.php
>   on line 40

The code is here:

```
        <?php
class Square_Form_ItemCreate extends Zend_Form
{
  public function init()
  {
    // initialize form
    $this->setAction('/catalog/item/create')
         ->setMethod('post');

    // create text input for name 
    $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('SellerName');
    $name->setLabel('Name:')
         ->setOptions(array('size' => '35'))
         ->setRequired(true)
         ->addValidator('Regex', false, array(
            'pattern' => '/^[a-zA-Z]+[A-Za-z\'\-\. ]{1,50}$/'
           ))            
         ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
         ->addFilter('StringTrim');            

    // create text input for email address
    $email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('SellerEmail');
    $email->setLabel('Email address:');
    $email->setOptions(array('size' => '50'))
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->addValidator('EmailAddress', false)            
          ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
          ->addFilter('StringTrim')            
          ->addFilter('StringToLower');        


    // create text input for tel number
    $tel = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('SellerTel');
    $tel->setLabel('Telephone number:');
    $tel->setOptions(array('size' => '50'))
        ->addValidator('StringLength', false, array('min' => 8))
        ->addValidator('Regex', false, array(
            'pattern'   => '/^\+[1-9][0-9]{6,30}$/',
            'messages'  => array(
              Zend_Validate_Regex::INVALID    => 
                '\'%value%\' does not match international number format +XXYYZZZZ',
              Zend_Validate_Regex::NOT_MATCH  => 
                '\'%value%\' does not match international number format +XXYYZZZZ'
            )
          ))
        ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
        ->addFilter('StringTrim');          


    // create text input for address
    $address = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('SellerAddress');
    $address->setLabel('Postal address:')
          ->setOptions(array('rows' => '6','cols' => '36'))
          ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
          ->addFilter('StringTrim');            

    // create text input for item title
    $title = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Title');
    $title->setLabel('Title:')
          ->setOptions(array('size' => '60'))
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
          ->addFilter('StringTrim');            

    // create text input for item year
    $year = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Year');
    $year->setLabel('Year:')
         ->setOptions(array('size' => '8', 'length' => '4'))
         ->setRequired(true)
         ->addValidator('Between', false, array('min' => 1700, 'max' => 2015))            
         ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
         ->addFilter('StringTrim');            

    // create select input for item country
    $country = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('CountryID');
    $country->setLabel('Country:')
            ->setRequired(true)    
            ->addValidator('Int')            
            ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')            
            ->addFilter('StringToUpper'); 
    foreach ($this->getCountries() as $c) {
      $country->addMultiOption($c['CountryID'], $c['CountryName']);      
    }        

    // create text input for item denomination
    $denomination = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('Denomination');
    $denomination->setLabel('Denomination:')
                 ->setOptions(array('size' => '8'))
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->addValidator('Float')            
                 ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
                 ->addFilter('StringTrim');            

    // create radio input for item type
    $type = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('TypeID');
    $type->setLabel('Type:')
         ->setRequired(true)
         ->addValidator('Int')            
         ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
         ->addFilter('StringTrim');
    foreach ($this->getTypes() as $t) {
      $type->addMultiOption($t['TypeID'], $t['TypeName']);      
    }        
    $type->setValue(1);

    // create select input for item grade
    $grade = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('GradeID');
    $grade->setLabel('Grade:')
          ->setRequired(true)    
          ->addValidator('Int')            
          ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
          ->addFilter('StringTrim');            
    foreach ($this->getGrades() as $g) {
      $grade->addMultiOption($g['GradeID'], $g['GradeName']);      
    };        

    // create text input for sale price (min)
    $priceMin = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('SalePriceMin');
    $priceMin->setLabel('Sale price (min):')
                 ->setOptions(array('size' => '8'))
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->addValidator('Float')            
                 ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
                 ->addFilter('StringTrim');            

    // create text input for sale price (max)
    $priceMax = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('SalePriceMax');
    $priceMax->setLabel('Sale price (max):')
                 ->setOptions(array('size' => '8'))
                 ->setRequired(true)
                 ->addValidator('Float')            
                 ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
                 ->addFilter('StringTrim');            

    // create text input for item description
    $notes = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('Description');
    $notes->setLabel('Description:')
          ->setOptions(array('rows' => '15','cols' => '60'))
          ->setRequired(true)
          ->addFilter('HtmlEntities')            
          ->addFilter('StripTags')            
          ->addFilter('StringTrim');           

    // create CAPTCHA for verification          
    $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('Captcha', array(
      'captcha' => array(
        'captcha' => 'Image',
        'wordLen' => 6,
        'timeout' => 300,
        'width'   => 300,
        'height'  => 100,
        'imgUrl'  => '/captcha',
        'imgDir'  => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/captcha',
        'font'    => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/fonts/LiberationSansRegular.ttf',
        )
    ));          

    // create submit button
    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setLabel('Submit Entry')
           ->setOrder(100)
           ->setOptions(array('class' => 'submit'));

    // attach elements to form    
    $this->addElement($name)
         ->addElement($email)
         ->addElement($tel)
         ->addElement($address);

    // create display group for seller information
    $this->addDisplayGroup(array('SellerName', 'SellerEmail', 'SellerTel', 'SellerAddress'), 'contact');
    $this->getDisplayGroup('contact')
         ->setOrder(10)
         ->setLegend('Seller Information');

    // attach elements to form    
    $this->addElement($title)
         ->addElement($year)
         ->addElement($country)
         ->addElement($denomination)
         ->addElement($type)
         ->addElement($grade)
         ->addElement($priceMin)
         ->addElement($priceMax)
         ->addElement($notes);

    // create display group for item information
    $this->addDisplayGroup(array('Title', 'Year', 'CountryID', 'Denomination', 'TypeID', 'GradeID', 'SalePriceMin', 'SalePriceMax', 'Description'), 'item');
    $this->getDisplayGroup('item')
         ->setOrder(20)
         ->setLegend('Item Information');

    // attach element to form    
    $this->addElement($captcha);

    // create display group for CAPTCHA
    $this->addDisplayGroup(array('Captcha'), 'verification');
    $this->getDisplayGroup('verification')
         ->setOrder(30)
         ->setLegend('Verification Code');

    // attach element to form    
    $this->addElement($submit);    
  }

  public function getCountries() {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->from('Square_Model_Country c');   
    return $q->fetchArray();
  }

  public function getGrades() {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->from('Square_Model_Grade g');   
    return $q->fetchArray();
  }

  public function getTypes() {
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
         ->from('Square_Model_Type t');   
    return $q->fetchArray();
  }

}
```

The error is coming from Zend_Validate_Regex::INVALID, but I can't seem to find any site that might explain why this error is occurring.

Can anyone help me with this? Is this normal or am I missing something here?

I've spent hours trying to figure this out for myself and have read through documentation, but apparently I'm missing something... I thought that it may be because I need to instantiate Zend_Validate_Regex, but when I do I just get a blank page, so I figured that I wasn't supposed to.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that the constant `INVALID` is not defined in the class `Zend_Validate_Regex`. Are you sure that you have Zend Framework set up correctly? That constant should be there, [according to the docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/).

Comment: Really strange, but you're right - it wasn't defined, although it should be, according to the documentation. I simply added it in "const INVALID = 'regexInvalid';"  and now it's working! Thanks!

Comment: PS I simply downloaded the latest version and replaced the Validate/Regex.php file and it works perfectly fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about the accepted part, but couldn't vote it up yet due to lack of reputation.