# Receiving PHP Fatal Error When Using pdo_mysql Attributes

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, pdo

I am trying to use SSL with PDO and PDO MySQL but receiving a "PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'" for:

```
    $this->db = new PDO(
        "mysql:host=".$this->hostname.";dbname=".$this->database, 
        $this->username, 
        $this->password, 
        array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => "path/to/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem" 
        )
    );
```

I have made sure that pdo_mysql is installed using phpinfo() and have had no problems using the code without SSL.  I am on Ubuntu 3.9 using PHP 5.3.6-13.  I have tried using other MYSQL_ATTR_.. and receive a similar error. Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808574/fatal-error-undefined-class-constant-invalid

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I realize that the constant is not defined in the class and that it should be.  I am just not clear as to why this documented constant does not exist since it appears that I have installed php_mysql correctly according to phpinfo().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` was defined as a constant 5.3.7 onwards.

You can look this up in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-ssl-ca

Comment: "path/to/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem" i don't have this pem file. where do i get it from

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting this error while working with Drush (Drupal command line tool, version 8.1.2) and Drupal (version 7.43). The problem was I was using PHP7 in the CLI, switching to PHP5.6 solved the problem.

Comment: Hi Peter. I am working with WAMP and WSL, my PHP is 5.6.16 and I get the same error on a Drupal 7.44 site and Druah 8.1.2 ... Any advice?

Comment: Hey, how you appoached that switch back?

Comment: If you're using PHP 7.0 and get this error, make sure you've installed `php7.0-mysql` and `php7.0-pdo` (if using Debian/Ubuntu—different packages on other OSes), and also make sure you restart your webserver or PHP-FPM.